# Hashmap to multiple graphs

Tags: java

I have a hashmap that is setup like this:

```
{ 192.168.2.10 = [192.167.2.10, 192.168.3.10] }
```

The key is the first router(source) and the following IP's are the destination.

I need the hashmap to be converted into a graph so that I can find the shortest path.

The end goal is that this is going to be a network simulator with packets. Each router must hold 50 packets. I must send a packet to the final destination  but I must find the shortest path to that destination.

Comment: So what does shortest path even mean here.  Do you really need a graph to find shortest path?

Comment: Sorry, yes I probably should have included more informaton I apologize. I am editing it right now.

Comment: I think the structure is already a graph. It is OK as is. Your algorithm should work over this multimap and create i.e. a list of IPs from A to B which is the shortest path according to some weight measure you haven't provided yet. (Or maybe the shortest path just refers to the number of IPs, please clearify all these details, so we can be of help).

Comment: Alright I had a bit of confusion when looking at the assignment. Okay I have the LinkedHashMap with each entry being like the one listed above. We have 10 IPs. Like above they are saved like this: { 192.168.2.10 = [192.167.2.10, 192.168.3.10] } the first IP is just saying it connects to the following IPs. I need to convert that to a graph. So I need to create nodes and edges from that

Answer (score 0):

To access sequentially key-value pairs in hashmap you need to use LinkedHashMap which stores keys in insertion order. You can access keys in both directions

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: Thanks I will look at that now.